# Conditional variables (ifeq) in foreach for explicit make rules

Tags: gnu-make

I can't figure out the correct syntax to use a conditionally defined variable with a foreach loop in GNU Make 3.81.

A simple makefile

```
SET := A B C

define da_loop

ifeq ($(S), A)
    T := equals_A
else
    T := not_equals_A
endif

out_$(S):
    echo "$(S) $$(T)"

endef

$(foreach S, $(SET), $(eval $(call da_loop, $S)))
```

Expected output:

```
$ make out_A out_B out_C
echo "A equals_A"
A equals_A
echo "B not_equals_A"
B not_equals_A
echo "C not_equals_A"
C not_equals_A
```

Actual output:

```
$ make out_A out_B out_C
echo "A not_equals_A"
A not_equals_A
echo "B not_equals_A"
B not_equals_A
echo "C not_equals_A"
C not_equals_A
```

Changing "eval" to "info" looks to me like this ought to work:

```
ifeq (A, A)
        T := equals_A
else
        T := not_equals_A
endif

out_A:
        echo "A $(T)"


ifeq (B, A)
        T := equals_A
else
        T := not_equals_A
endif

out_B:
        echo "B $(T)"


ifeq (C, A)
        T := equals_A
else
        T := not_equals_A
endif

out_C:
        echo "C $(T)"
```

I've tried every combination of extra "$", quotes, = vs :=, that I can think of, but none have worked yet.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with loops, `eval`, etc.  The problem is simpler and more fundamental than that: in make, variables are *globally defined*, and all rules are only invoked after the entire makefile has been parsed.  The `info` trick actually DID show you the problem.  Let's simplify it a bit:

```
T := equals_A
out_A:
        echo "A $(T)"

T := not_equals_A
out_B:
        echo "B $(T)"

T := not_equals_A
out_C:
        echo "C $(T)"
```

The problem is that all variable assignment happens when the makefile is read in, but expansion of recipes doesn't happen until much later, when make is building targets and decides to run the recipe.  So, your makefile could be written equivalently as:

```
T := equals_A
T := not_equals_A
T := not_equals_A

out_A:
        echo "A $(T)"
out_B:
        echo "B $(T)"
out_C:
        echo "C $(T)"
```

Now you can see why you get the behavior you do.

There are numerous ways to "fix" this, which of them is most appropriate depends on what you really want to do in your real makefile.  A very simple option is to use [target-specific variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html), like this:

```
SET := A B C

define da_loop

ifeq ($(S), A)
    out_$(S): T := equals_A
else
    out_$(S): T := not_equals_A
endif

out_$(S):
        echo "$(S) $$(T)"

endef

$(foreach S, $(SET), $(eval $(call da_loop, $S)))
```

By using this, you've specified that each `T` variable is bound to the scope of that specific target and every target can have a different value.  Other options would be constructed variable names, or simply expanding the value directly into the recipe using the `$(if ...)` function, rather than setting it as a separate variable.

Comment: Target-specific variables work!

FYI: my goal is to put an additional flag in the command when $(T) = A, but not when $(T) = B or C.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

ifeq of course has another syntax (with quotes),
where no stripping of white-space is done inside the quoted text!